# Http_proxy environment variable is present in terminal but not in Jenkins run

Tags: environment-variables, jenkins

In `/etc/profile` ,we have `http_proxy` variable is set.
When we run the command `env` from terminal(logged in via ssh in putty) it shows it correctly.

But when we tried to run `env` command from Jenkins this variable is not present.
In `/etc/profile` the `http_proxy` is exported. Below is my `/etc/profile`

```
MY_PROXY_URL="http://web-proxy.corp.mycorp.net:8080"
HTTP_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
HTTPS_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
FTP_PROXY=$MY_PROXY_URL
http_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
https_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL
ftp_proxy=$MY_PROXY_URL

export HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy
```

When we run below commands in jenkins

```
if [ -z $PS1 ] # no prompt?
then
  echo "non-interactive"
else
  echo "interactive"
fi
```

It displayed as non-interactive. So we tried the below, In .bashrc file we put this

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] ; then
        source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

But still `env` displays not `http_ptoxy`. Please help.
We are using Centos 7.7 VM

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jenkins uses `sh`, not `bash`, to execute shell steps.

> From the help/question mark icon of the "Execute shell" section:
>
> ```
> Runs a shell script (defaults to sh, but this is configurable) for building the project.
> ```
>
> If you go to Manage Jenkins --> Configure System you will find an
> option (called "Shell executable") to set the name or absolute path to
> the shell that you want your shell scripts to use...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12457930/1824868